# UITextView that becomes scrollable once a max height is reached in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I currently have a non-scrollable UITextView that expands dynamically to fit any text. However, what I'm having difficulty figuring out is how to stop the textview from increasing in height if gets bigger than a set height - at which point, I'd like for it to become scrollable.

**Image**

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmBzm.png)

Green: biggerParentView

Yellow: parentViewContainer

Cyan: randomLabel

Red: myTextView

**Setting myTextView**

```
myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myTextView.text = "This is a large chunck that has no meaning, especially to everyone reading this."
myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false        

parentViewContainer.addSubview(myTextView)
```

**Constraints**

```
parentViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: biggerParentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
parentViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: biggerParentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
parentViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: randomLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
parentViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTextView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

randomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentViewContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
randomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentViewContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
randomLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

myTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentViewContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
myTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentViewContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
myTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: randomLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

**Question**

The current example works for short texts, but if I were going to change the text in myTextView to the entirety of *A Tale of Two Cities*, myTextView, along with its parentViewContainer, would expand forever offscreen. How can I ensure that myTextView and its parent can only expand so far dynamically, at which point myTextView would become scrollable?

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p531selfSizingTextView/ch23p811selfSizingTextField/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) for pointing me in the right direction. The key is to put the logic in viewDidLayoutSubviews().

```
var myTextViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    myTextViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0)
    myTextViewHeightConstraint.isActive = false
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let h = self.myTextView.contentSize.height
    let limit = self.myTextView.frame.height - randomLabel.frame.height - 20 //20 is the distance constraint between randomLabel and myTextView

    if h > limit && !self.myTextView.isScrollEnabled {
           self.myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
           self.myTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = limit
           self.myTextViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
           }

     else if h < limit && self.myTextView.isScrollEnabled {     
           self.myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
           self.myTextViewHeightConstraint.isActive = false
     }
   }
}
```